# Does excessive menthol cause sleepiness?

Tags: biology, sleep, herbalism

Does over consumption of menthol cause sleepiness?

I found no substantial sources either to suport or refute this argument. I have heard it from a few sources not perfectly reliable.

I do know that consumption of cough drops does cause.

By over comsumption I mean taking 3/4 tablets per hour.

I am consuming "fishermen's friend" "extra stark" and want to check if it is true.

Comment: Everything that contains sugar can make you tired, because of sugar crashes.

Comment: I am skeptical that 10/15 I consumed within couple of hours would cause so much sleepiness. Maybe, but I would love to know menthol itself contributes.

Comment: many things containing menthol also contain a lot of sugar, which can cause a sugar rush, followed by sleepiness. So it should not be surprising if people start linking the two, but get the causality wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

At typical dosages, Menthol's side effects do not include drowsiness. They do include:

> Severe allergic reactions (rash; hives; itching; difficulty breathing; tightness in the chest; swelling of the mouth, face, lips, or tongue); redness or irritation at the application site.  [[source](http://www.drugs.com/sfx/menthol-side-effects.html)]

At overdose levels, Menthol's side-effects do not include drowsiness. They do include:

> - Bladder and kidneys
>
>   - Blood in the urine
>   - No urine output
> - Lungs
>
>   - Rapid breathing
>   - Shallow breathing
> - Gastrointestinal
>
>   - Abdominal pain
>   - Diarrhea
>   - Nausea
>   - Vomiting
> - Heart and blood
>
>   - Rapid heartbeat
> - Nervous system
>
>   - Convulsions
>   - Dizziness
>   - Tremor
>   - Unconsciousness
>   - Unsteady walking
>
> [[source](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/002673.htm)]

Use medications according to the instructions. On average, they are more reliable than the Internet.